# Fail2ban Auto Whitelist

Tags: fail2ban

We use fail2ban on a number of our servers for blocking brute-force attempts against services like SSH, SMTP, IMAP, SIP, etc, and it works very well. However, we get a lot of false positives under certain common circumstances.

Most of our clients are small businesses. So all of their users are on a local LAN behind a NAT'd firewall. So it's common for 10 users to authenticate with, say, their email account just fine. But then one user enters the credentials wrong a few times, and the entire office (coming from a single public IP) is banned on our side.

I'd like for fail2ban to have a bit of intelligence to its process. Something along the lines of "If we see successful authentications from this IP address, then let's whitelist it for a bit, because future failed logins are almost certainly genuine failures and not brute-force attacks."

We have clients with static IPs at their offices and those with dynamic IPs. Manually whitelisting the dynamic IPs is obviously a no-go. But even for static IPs it would be a nightmare to try to manage those manually. As a brute-force IP is banned for a period of time, it'd be good to auto-whitelist an IP for a period of time once we detect a successful authentication attempt from it so that it can't be banned.

Is this something that can be done with some clever fail2ban rules?

Comment: It's not a native concept of fail2ban as far as I'm aware but I think with a custom filter and custom ban action, it might be hackable. The filter would have to match successful authentication while the banaction would whitelist the IP. I'll have a look after the weekend if you haven't managed by then 

Comment: @Ginnungagap I found this (https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/fail2ban-action-whitelist/) and have been working on implementing that for Asterisk. I'm having difficulty with the regex, so I've posted a question here (https://serverfault.com/questions/1132529/fail2ban-match-asterisk-pjsip-successful-authentication) for that.

Comment: I know that you want a pure fail2ban solution, but what if you ask your clients to use a DDNS service? In this way you could check what are their IPs, day by day, hour by hour...

Answer (score 0):

> If we see successful authentications from this IP address, then let's whitelist it for a bit, because future failed logins are almost certainly genuine failures and not brute-force attacks.

However it can probably protect against few false positives, this is questionable practice for several reasons.
The main are:

- a single compromised PC in such a subnet can unhindered do a brute force and other stuff and will be ignored if an IP/subnet was added to ignorelist;
- it opens a vector which may allow to escalate privileges for some user with fewer rights or for an account theft of other user - some user, that has a valid account, can try to login with another account, and then simply does a successful login (with his own account), so quasi resets the count of failed attempts or still worse adds the IP/subnet to the whitelist.

So at least it must consider the user name, see the discussion in [[github]/fail2ban#PR-1243](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/1243).

But you can try to implement the idea using `ignorecommand`. Here is an example for such implementation - [[github]/fail2ban#2013, comment-426940189](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2013#issuecomment-426940189).

Also note that fail2ban is able to ban [basically everything](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-to-ban-something-other-as-host-(IP-address),-like-user-or-mail,-etc.), so in such case a combination of `<ip>` with `<F-USER>` should be probably used as ban identifier.
Alternatively a "proxying" address behind NAT could be also used together with a customers' real IP address.

Anyway, no matter how you'd implement that, ensure you really understand what you do and the risks involved as well as preventive measures to avoid them.

Comment: I'd be whitelisting individual IPs only, not subnets. The probability that an attacker (whether that be intentionally or through infection) exists on the same network as a whitelisted IP is exceedingly tiny, and worth the risk for me.