# Fail2Ban - Match Asterisk PJSIP Successful Authentication

Tags: fail2ban, asterisk

I'm trying to create a fail2ban filter that will match *successful* authentications. An example log entry looks like this:

```
[2023-05-25 18:41:00] VERBOSE[26149] res_pjsip/pjsip_options.c: Contact user/sip:58l3je69@192.168.0.110:47682;transport=ws;x-ast-orig-host=b0cnalpndgjm.invalid:0 is now Reachable.  RTT: 27.843 msec
```

I am not well-versed in creating fail2ban filters, but here's my attempt (I started by copying the asterisk.conf in filter.d to asterisk-whitelist.conf to use as a template, then changed failregex in an attempt to match lines like the above):

```
[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf

[Definition]

_daemon = asterisk

__pid_re = (?:\s*\[\d+\])

iso8601 = \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+[+-]\d{4}

# All Asterisk log messages begin like this:
log_prefix= (?:NOTICE|SECURITY|WARNING)%(__pid_re)s:?(?:\[C-[\da-f]*\])? [^:]+:\d*(?:(?: in)? \w+:)?

prefregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s%(log_prefix)s <F-CONTENT>.+</F-CONTENT>$

failregex = ^Contact [A-Za-z0-9]+/sip:[A-Za-z0-9]+@<HOST>:[0-9]+;transport=[A-Za-z]+;[A-Za-z]+=[A-Za-z0-9\.]+:0 is now Reachable\.  RTT: [0-9]*\.[0-9]+ msec$
ignoreregex =
```

The above isn't working. I'm not particularly sure how to go about troubleshooting this, or what change needs to be made to match. The result of `fail2ban-regex /var/log/asterisk/full asterisk-whitelist.conf` shows 0 matches.

Updated to add the final resolution with help from the accepted answer. Here's the config that ultimately worked for me:

```
[INCLUDES]
# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf

[Definition]
_daemon = asterisk

__pid_re = (?:\s*\[\d+\])

iso8601 = \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+[+-]\d{4}

# All Asterisk log messages begin like this:
log_prefix= (?:NOTICE|SECURITY|WARNING|VERBOSE)%(__pid_re)s:?(?:\[C-[\da-f]*\])? [^:]+:\d*(?:(?: in)? \w+:)?

prefregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s%(log_prefix)s <F-CONTENT>.+</F-CONTENT>$

failregex = ^.*Contact .*\/sip[s]?:.*@<HOST>.* is now Reachable.*

ignoreregex =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is too complex and wrong, try this one `failregex = ^.*Contact .*\/sip:[^@]+@<HOST>.* is now Reachable.*`

You can test it with `fail2ban-regex /var/log/asterisk/full /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/asterisk-whitelist.conf`

edit: lets try something else, lets replace the content of `asterisk-whitelist.conf` with this conf, it should match the log you provided.

```
[INCLUDES]
# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf

[Definition]
_daemon = asterisk

__pid_re = (?:\s*\[\d+\])

iso8601 = \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+[+-]\d{4}

# All Asterisk log messages begin like this:
log_prefix= (?:NOTICE|SECURITY|WARNING)%(__pid_re)s:?(?:\[C-[\da-f]*\])? [^:]+:\d*(?:(?: in)? \w+:)?

prefregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s%(log_prefix)s <F-CONTENT>.+</F-CONTENT>$

failregex = ^\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\] %(__pid_re)s res_pjsip/pjsip_options\.c: Contact user/sip:[^@]+@<HOST>:\d+;transport=[\w-]+;x-ast-orig-host=[\w.-]+:0 is now Reachable\.  RTT: \d+\.\d+ msec$

ignoreregex =
```

Comment: "Too complex and wrong" is an accurate description of my attempt. :-) However, I tested with what you provided and it doesn't match either. The log file I'm testing against has nearly 400k lines and a quick grep for "is now Reachable" shows that there are 379 lines that should match. Thoughts?

Comment: I have modified my answer, it should work :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, still no matches.

Comment: I got this working with two minor changes. First, I used your initial simpler regex, but I had to add VERBOSE to the log_prefix definition (I should have been paying more attention to that, as your first suggestion worked after I noticed that). Second, sometimes the URL has "sips" instead of "sip", so I made a minor change. The final changed entries are `log_prefix= (?:NOTICE|SECURITY|WARNING|VERBOSE)%(__pid_re)s:?(?:\[C-[\da-f]*\])? [^:]+:\d*(?:(?: in)? \w+:)?` and `failregex = ^.*Contact .*\/sip[s]?:.*@<HOST>.* is now Reachable.*`.